# Ansible open port on iptables

Tags: iptables, centos6, ansible

Currently I am changing the port for remote machine. I also have to allow the firewall rules on Centos 6.9. The folling is my command to open the port 2222 on sshd. I do not know how to open port 2222 on iptables using ansible. Can someone help?

```
- hosts: web

  tasks:
   - name: Change The default Port for SSH

     lineinfile: dest=/etc/ssh/sshd_config

                 regexp="#Port 22"
                 line="Port 2222"
                 state=present
   - name: Restart sshd
     service: 

        name: 'sshd'
        state: 'restarted'
```

Comment: Did you look at [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/iptables_module.html)?

Answer (score 0):

as always there are several ways to achieve a specific goal on ansible, and iptables rules is no exception. hbut here I'll leave you a way to open port 2222 on iptables

```
- iptables_raw:
    name: allow_tcp_2222
    rules: '-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your firewall is managed by system-config-firewall then you can use `lokkit` to open firewall ports. For example:

```
- name: Open nonstandard ssh port in system-config-firewall
  command: lokkit -p 2222:tcp
  when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' and ansible_distribution_major_version|int == 6

- name: Open standard ssh port in system-config-firewall
  command: lokkit -s ssh
  when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' and ansible_distribution_major_version|int == 6
```